# Ontouch event of OnTouchListener gets called twice in android

Tags: android

I am creating an appliction in which a line gets generated between two points given at runtime.
The problem that I see is that `onTouch()` is called twice for every click on my simulator. I know that two actions (`ACTION_DOWN` & `ACTION_UP`) are checked. But I want my app to call `onTouch()` just once. Please give me some ideas. This is the code that I used:

```
SurfaceView surfaceview = new SurfaceView(getContext());
SurfaceHolder h = surfaceview.getHolder();
int action = event.getActionMasked();
synchronized(h) {
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && action!=MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)// && flag==true)
    {
        Log.d("TouchView","ACTION_DOWN ");
        Point pointer = new Point();
        pointer.x = (int) event.getX();
        pointer.y = (int) event.getY();
        touchPoint.add(pointer);
        view.invalidate();
        Log.d("MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN", "point: " + pointer);
        action = MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL;
        flag = false;
    }
    else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && action!=MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)// && flag==true)
    {
        Log.d("TouchView","ACTION_UP");
        Point pointer = new Point();
        pointer.x = (int) event.getX();
        pointer.y = (int) event.getY();
        touchPoint.add(pointer);
        view.invalidate();
        Log.d("MotionEvent.ACTION_UP", "point: " + pointer);
        action = MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL;
        flag = false;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 186, accepted):

touchListener will be called for every `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, and `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` . so if you want to execute code only once , ie `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` 
then inside

```
onTouch()
 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
//your code 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Didn't think a touch on a button/link is like two click actions.

Comment: @raja explain yourself `int action = event.getAction(); if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){ ...}`

Comment: for me it get  called 4 times now it's twice thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

Or just use onClickListener:

```
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do what you gotta do
            }
        });
```

Comment: Dpedrinha, one reason to use onTouchListener would be to register clicks on a spinner, because an onClickListener may not be used with Spinners.

Comment: If you don't need the extra information of the MotionEvent data, this is the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes dealing with many views under the same parent cause the onTouch called many times (if they're above each other) the solution for me was

```js
onTouch{ ...
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && isTouchEnabled()){
            enableTouch(false);
            //add your code here 
            
            //then enableTouch at the end 
            this.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    enableTouch(true);

                }
            }, 500);
      }
      add static variable touch
    private static boolean enabled = true;
      
    private void enableTouch(boolean enabled){
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    private boolean isTouchEnabled(){
        return enabled;
    }
```