# Multi touch callin two tomes ACTION_DOWN?

Tags: android, touch

I am trying to listen multitouch in android following define steps [here](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html).

But the problem I am getting in onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) ACTION_DOWN is calling two times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify only event `ACTION_DOWN`, if you want your code only running when event  `ACTION_DOWN` is happened :

[Ontouch event of OnTouchListener gets called twice in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182513/ontouch-event-of-ontouchlistener-gets-called-twice-in-android)

If you dont specify what you want, then yes. `onTouchListener` will be called multiple times because there is multiple events (see the link above, it has good explanation and show case).

Comment: I know onTouchEvent will call multiple times but why it is going in ACTION_DOWN two times.

Comment: @Avi have you specify your `onTouchClick`? Please post your code