# Android intent to another activity being executed multiple times

Tags: android, android-intent, android-logcat

I have an intent that when the user touches anywhere on the splashscreen activity they're directed to the gallery activity, this seemingly works fine for the most part and when running the app does as is expected until the back button is pressed. When pressed multiple presses are required to return to the splashscreen.

Using logcat I was able to find out that the intent is being run multiple times however I'm unable to understand why, here's the method for the intent.

```
private void FullScreenOnTouchEvent() {

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_splashscreen_layout);

    layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Splashscreen.this, Gallery.class));
            Log.d("Splashscreen", "splashscreen executed");
            return true;            
        }

    });
}
```

I placed a check when the intent was executed and the new activity (gallery) had opened, the messages displayed are "splashscreen executed" and "gallery executed" respectively.
Here's a copy of the logcat.

splashscreen executed /
Gallery has executed /
splashscreen executed / 
Gallery has executed /

I'm unable to see why this is ocurring and i'm at a bit of a deadend research wise, any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Damon.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8182589/4224337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*onTouch()* is being called multiple times since it recognizes touch inputs of many kinds (DOWN, UP, MOVE...). You can fix this by an example written [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182513/ontouch-event-of-ontouchlistener-gets-called-twice-in-android/8182589#8182589) or change layout listener to the [*OnClickListener*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) which would be more simple to implement (less code).